# Extracting zope data.fs

Tags: python, plone, zope

I had a zope/plone site where I stored pictures and videos from several users, but I want to move the content to another site now. What is the easiest way to extract content of Zope's data.fs? I heard there were python modules for this but I want to avoid writing code from scratch if possible. I'm using Ubuntu 9.04 with python 2.6.

EDIT: my intension is not moving the content to another plone site, I want to extract the content as regular files and build a new(probably non-plone) site from scratch. I don't have a working plone site now because Ubuntu 9.04 doesn't support it.  Sorry for being ambigious.

Answer (score 3):

The ZODB is a full object database, and data inside it is not stored as files. You could compare it with, for example, postgres: it is not possible to just turn your postgres data into a bunch of files.

There are several options to extract data from your ZODB that might work for you:

- you can enable the FTP service for Zope. See the zope.conf configuration file for details
  (it has many comments explaining the options). Once you have FTP enabled you can extract
  most data with any standard FTP client.
- there are several data import/export products available for Plone. Perhaps one of those
  will work for you.

Unfortunately both options rely on you being able to run Zope, which you state you can not do. I am guessing that is due to Plone requiring Zope 2.10 or older, which only run on python 2.4. If so you could try to compile an older python version and install that on your system. Python fully supports having multiple versions installed at the same time, so that should not break anything else on your system.

I am afraid it is not possible to extract data from the ZODB without running any python tools, and to be able to load Plone data from the ZODB you will need to have a working Plone environment so ZODB can load the python classes for the data stored in it.

Answer (score 1):

tres seaver has written a product that does a lot of what you want - i don't know about images though, but probably.

if I remember right it is called fsdump.

Comment: Unfortunately, fsdump is also a zope product, and is installed into a zope instance. My problem is that I cannot run my instance, because of stupid python incompatibilities of plone and ubuntu.

Comment: Didn't catch that last one - well in that case - good luck. One thing You could try though was to install plone on windows (if you have that...) - it comes with a one-click installer, after that try to copy the database over and then reinstall all the broken products you would want. And then fsdump (if that works on windows) or use a manual approach.

Answer (score 0):

in the ZMI tick the site in the root folder then click the export button, this will create a file in $PLONE/exports, on your new server server in the ZMI click import and point to this file, zope will then import it just as it was on the other server.

Comment: Sorry for miswording my question, I want to extract the content as files, not to move it into another Plone site.